# How to convert a plain text into a structured PowerShell object

Tags: powershell

I have a generic text, not PSCustom, not CSV, not JSON but has some structure

```
Field1:ABC
Field2: DEF

Field1:HKA
Field3:YZ

Field1:123
Field2:234
Field4:876
Field5:XUZ
```

Obviously, the text is a multiple records with fields and missing fields, each record is separated with CR-LF.

Is there an efficient way to parse the string and extract only `Field1` and `Field2` out of the records and put the results in JSON?

I tried put the string into a string variable called `$s` then

```
$s | select -ExpandProperty Field1,Field2
```

But I got this error

> Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. Specified method is not supported.

If I tried

```
$s | select -ExpandProperty Field1
```

Then I got the error saying `Field1` not being a property.

I guess I kinda understand the error but not sure how to fix it. I think I have to somehow convert the text into a structured table first then extract it. But how do I do that?

Comment: You're trying to expand a 'property' on a string. This won't work. You have to create a PSCustom Object and place the values into that object, then you can use it in the pipe and expand properties that way. The solution I could think of is split the string on a new line into an array and use a foreach loop on that to create your custom object.

Comment: I also notice you have multiable field1's and 2's and so forth....Is this sample you gave correct?

Comment: @ArcSet: Yes, it is. The "plain text" is not actually plain text but structured one. They are records with field1, field2,...,fieldn. Some fields show up because they have values, some don't since they are blank. But I am only interested in specific fields, let's say field1 and field2. If they are blank, then I would leave space in the value.

Answer (score 3):

`Select-Object` won't work on a string. You need to process the string into a list of objects first. Also, you cannot expand more than one property at a time.

Split the text at 2+ consecutive line breaks:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\input.txt' | Out-String) -split '(\r?\n){2,}'
```

Split each fragment into lines, split each line at the separator, and fill a hashtable with the key/value pairs:

```
$ht = @{}
$fragment -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*:\s*'
    $ht[$key] = $value
}
```

Then build objects from the hashtables:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht
```

With that you can select the properties `Field1` and `Field2` like this:

```
... | Select-Object Field1, Field2
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very slick... However, for some reason, after running the script, the fields from all records are combined into only 1 record... so $ht is only one record with Field1 to Field5 while I was looking for is $ht[0]={Field1:..,Field2}, $ht[1]={Field1...,Field3],$ht[3]={...}.... I probably need to twist your code a bit to get what I want, but at least I got the gist of what should be done!

Comment: Most likely you didn't create a new hashtable for each fragment

Comment: ah... that's probably it! I am new and still learning my ropes